# typescript dynamic and safe adding element to array

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamic, types

I'm porting a Javascript application to Typescript. 
I have an object with many array properties containing data and a javscript function do access the data arrays. For simplicity I consider only the add method

```
function updateDataStructure(state, structureName, elem) {
   state.data[structureName].push(elem);
   return state.data[structureName];
}
```

Porting to typescript I'd like to introduce type safety and maintain generic code.

```
interface AA {
    lep: string,
    snap: number,
    sul: boolean
}

interface BB {
    p1: string;
    val: number;
}

interface StateDataContainer {
    aa: AA[],
    bb: BB[],
}

class State {
    data: StateDataContainer;
}

export type DataContainerProps = keyof StateDataContainer;
type ArrayElement<ArrayType> = ArrayType extends (infer ElementType)[] ? ElementType : never;

function updateDataStructure<K extends DataContainerProps, D extends ArrayElement<StateDataContainer[K]>>
                (state: State, structureName: K, elem: D)
    : StateDataContainer[K] {

    // @ts-ignore
    state.data[structureName].push(elem);
    return state.data[structureName];
}
```

With this code I have a typed safe interface, the compiler checks the client code to add the proper objects into the right structure.

```
const state = new State();

let avv: BB;
let line: AA;

let v: BB[] = updateDataStructure(state, 'bb', avv!);
let l: AA[] = updateDataStructure(state, 'aa', line!);
```

with this solution I have to add use the  // @ts-ignore annotation in the implementation code to avoid compiler errors like:

```
 Argument of type 'D' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AA & BB'.
  Type 'ArrayElement<StateDataContainer[K]>' is not assignable to type 'AA & BB'.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'AA & BB'.
      Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'AA'.
        Type 'AA | BB' is not assignable to type 'AA & BB'.
```

Is there a better approach to write this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the other issue is that TypeScript doesn't understand the semantics of your `ArrayElement` type, i.e. it doesn't know it means something that you can append to `StateDataContainer[K]`.

One way to go around this issue is to define `state` in terms of `D`, i.e.

```
function updateDataStructure<K extends DataContainerProps, D extends ArrayElement<StateDataContainer[K]>>
    (state: { data: { [key in K]: D[] } }, structureName: K, elem: D)
    : D[] {

    state.data[structureName].push(elem);
    return state.data[structureName];
}
```

TypeScript playground: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20AA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20lep%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20snap%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sul%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20BB%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20p1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20val%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20StateDataContainer%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aa%3A%20AA%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bb%3A%20BB%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20StateDataContainer%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20DataContainerProps%20%3D%20keyof%20StateDataContainer%3B%0D%0Atype%20ArrayElement%3CArrayType%3E%20%3D%20ArrayType%20extends%20(infer%20ElementType)%5B%5D%20%3F%20ElementType%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20updateDataStructure%3CK%20extends%20DataContainerProps%2C%20D%20extends%20ArrayElement%3CStateDataContainer%5BK%5D%3E%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(state%3A%20%7B%20data%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20K%5D%3A%20D%5B%5D%20%7D%20%7D%2C%20structureName%3A%20K%2C%20elem%3A%20D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20D%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state.data%5BstructureName%5D.push(elem)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20state.data%5BstructureName%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20state%20%3D%20new%20State()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20avv%3A%20BB%3B%0D%0Alet%20line%3A%20AA%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20v%3A%20BB%5B%5D%20%3D%20updateDataStructure(state%2C%20'bb'%2C%20avv!)%3B%0D%0Alet%20l%3A%20AA%5B%5D%20%3D%20updateDataStructure(state%2C%20'aa'%2C%20line!)%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: Yes good idea, if I don't want modify signature I can also type cast the array `(state.data[structureName] as D[]).push(elem);` and `state.data[structureName] =
        (state.data[structureName] as D[]).filter( v => v) as StateDataContainer[K];`

Answer (score 0):

Your `structureName` param has the type `'aa' | 'bb'`, and your `elem` type is `AA | BB`. TypeScript currently doesn't narrow generics the way you would expect (see [#23578](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23578), [#24085](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085)).

In your example, note that the input/output types are still correct (you can't pass `line` in if your `structureName` is `'aa'`). So, if you're willing to sacrifice some type safety in your function implementation, here's a hack to get you unblocked:

```
     state.data[structureName as 'aa'].push(elem as AA);
```

Comment: Yes you are right, in method body the type of elem is AA | BB. I think it's not a question of safety because at push  the compiler has given us the assurance that the value  of structureName and the type of elem will conform.

Comment: To switch on structureName values and add custom push with the 
explicit cast for each value will increase the number of code lines reducing safety. I'm thinking if there is the possibility to cast `AA | BB as AA & BB`

Comment: Honestly I was thinking about even taking it further in the opposite direction and setting both`structureName` and `elem` to `any`. At this point more changes give you marginal gains at best. I'd recommend throwing a `// TODO` above this block of code and just wait until the compiler handles this properly in a future version.